# Adding new objects to a jframe

Tags: java, formatting, jframe, jpanel

I have seen a program and was hoping to replicate one feature of it in my program. The program is a flashcard app, and when you create a new deck it adds another section to the homescreeen. I will attach images. I would love some advice on how to do this.

[image]

Comment: So, it's basically a list of components, the component models some data and the whole thing is managed by some kind of controller. If you know how to add components dynamically to a container it shouldn't be that hard. I might even be easier just use a JTable, but that's me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible way is to use correct layouts, [here is examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Using this you may dynamically add any components (labels, images, buttons etc.) into your JPanel (I recommend to use JPanel as main container of all components instead of JFrame that should be one and just contain your JPanel).

Comment: Thanks for that! I have had a quick read. Which one would you suggest for my issue?

Comment: It can be mix of several layouts, for example main container has `BoxLayout` that contains panels where is `FlowLayout` and that panels contains your components. Or the better way is to use `GridBagLayout` it is very flexible and can cover all your requirements, just need understand how it works. Detailed explanation with examples for each layout exist on the same link (each layout has reference for detailed examples)

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful!! 

Comment: You are welcome, I did a lot of desktop app on Java, so if you will have some additional questions feel free to ask me.